# MS WOPI: When ppt file is open for edit after some time show Sign in with one of these accounts

Tags: ms-wopi

In MS WOPI, when the user edits a PPTX file it shows this message after some time.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How would you like it to behave?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to adjust the [`access_token_ttl`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/concepts.html#term-access-token-ttl)